# how to get avg time in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, intervals, average

I have table like this:

```
name   number   total_time    avg_time
tom      10      00:02:28        ?
kevin    6       09:22:25        ?
```

total_time is type of interval, I can easily change to string.
now, I want to get the avg_time like this

```
avg_time = total_time / number;
```

I wander how to get the result ? I try to calculate day, hour, min, sec, but it's too difficult , anyone who can give me some advice ? thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this example (based on yours) is helpful:

```
postgres=# SELECT *, total_time / number AS avg_time 
    FROM (SELECT INTERVAL '00:02:28' AS total_time, 10 AS number) a;
 total_time | number |  avg_time  
------------+--------+------------
 00:02:28   |     10 | 00:00:14.8
(1 row)
```

Can you be more specific about what part of this isn't working for you?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether is right, just easily use / is ok, like this

```
select interval '02:00:00'/4
```

i got the right answer, so the question maybe simple

```
select total_time / number
```

Answer (score 0):

The below uses epoch time and works perfect (18000 is the start of epoch)

```
select to_timestamp(avg(18000 + 
                        cast(extract(epoch from badge_in_time::time) as integer)
                       )
                   )::time as Avg_Badge_in
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but for a different question. This does not answer OP's question at all.

Answer (score -1):

you could also use the `avg` operator:
`select name, avg(total_time) from table group by name;`

Comment: Nope: Function avg(timestamp without time zone) does not exist